# How to load this file path from inside a spring application

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I was previously hard coding a path to load a json file like so:

```
JsonParser parser = jf.createJsonParser(new File("/some/path/here/myapp/WEB-INF/settings.json"));
```

So I tried to extract it out to a properties file like so, files.properties:

```
path.to.json=/some/path/here/myapp/WEB-INF/settings.json
```

Now how can I modify my call to `jf.createJsonParser` to load the file using the path from the files.properties `path.to/json` key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little confused.  Your title indicates that you are looking for a Spring solution, but you are not using IOC here, from what I can tell.  Otherwise, you would be injecting the `JsonParser` bean and not instantiating it within your code.

Without seeing the global structure of what you are doing, I would do the following (assuming that you have Spring properly configured).

applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="jsonParser" factory-bean="<jf bean definition>" factory-method="createJsonParer">
   <constructor-arg>classpath:/settings.json</constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Then within your actual class that uses the JsonParser, have it autowired for simplicity sake:

```
class myClass{
  @Autowired
  JsonParser jsonParser;

  public void myMethod(){
    String data = jsonParser.doSomthingNeatHere()....
  }

}
```

I've assumed that JsonParser is of scope prototype, but you can change it to singleton if that matches your needs more appropriately.  As well, I've only given you a little pseudo-code to give you the idea of how to allow Spring to manage the life-cycle of the bean as opposed to you instantiating it yourself.

You can read more about Spring 3 and IOC [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) if you need additional reference.

Comment: I just edited my response to match your original declaration a little bit better.  I do not know what "jf" is in "jf.createJsonParser", so I am referring to it as a factory-bean.  My answer assumes that you previously have defined a bean "jf".

Comment: I'm using spring, but I'm not wiring up all my beans for things that I deem as not important.  Is that a bad idea?

Comment: Overall, I would have to say yes.  Others might voice another opinion, but when you start to mix and match, you are not being consistent with your code, and more importantly, you are not allowing Spring to manage the lifecycle of your beans.  With annotations these days to automatically define your beans (ex: @ Component, @ Service, etc) and to inject (@ Autowire), there is little reason not to.  Furthermore, by ignoring those that are "not important", you are tying a bunch of implementations into the code (as opposed to configuration), which negates a huge benefit of IOC.

Answer (score 0):

If you can put your file into a source folder, do it and try `"classpath:/"`

Example:

```
new File( "classpath:/context/settings.json" );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether your looking for a Spring specific solution, but I see nothing wrong with using the JCL.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileReader(propsFile));
String jsonFile = props.getProperty("path.to.json");
JsonParser parser = jf.createJsonParser(new File(jsonFile));
```